# Strange form reaction when file uploaded

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, rest, file-upload

I have a simple form :

```
        <form action="http://localhost/api2/Users/Teachers/imageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
        <input type="hidden" name="X-API-KEY" value="21f5ba3c7ac34c81964f5e49b13b9b65914dhar2">
        var1: <input type="number" name="var1"  ></br>
        var2: <input type="number" name="var2"  ></br>
        image: <input type="file" name="img" multiple></br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

All this should do is send post request with the api-key, var1, var2 and the image file.

Now as long as the form doesn't try to send a file, everything works great. When I try to send an image, it is as if I sent an empty form.

Here is some of my backend:(I made this the default response just for testing.)

```
    $var1 = $this->post("var1");
    $var2 = $this->post("var2");
    $this->response(array("Error"=> TRUE,"message"=>"Missing arguments","data"=>array($var1,$var2,$_FILES)),500);
```

Response without file:

```
{
"Error": true,
"message": "Missing arguments",
"data": [
    "1",
    "2",
    []
    ]
}
```

Response with file:

```
{"Error":true,"message":"Access Denied"}
```

And if I send it via [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) I receive.

```
{
"Error": true,
"message": "Missing arguments",
"data": [
    false,
    false,
    []
    ]
}
```

I'm using [codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) as my `restAPI` controller. It was working just fine until I started uploading files.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?
Thank you.

Comment: Try to take out the "multiple" in the img one, and see if it works. If it does, then you know where your problem is.

Comment: them I'm not sure - I'm sorry.

Comment: You should use `name="img[]"` if using multiple option. Missing it should not create the behaviour you are describing, but who knows.

Comment: Its not working with or without the `multiple`. The form is just to test my back-end which is clearly faulty in some way. I posted the "essence" of my backend. Also i have been testing with `Postman` plugin and I found that when a file is passed everything after `Headers` is not passed (form-data). maybe this is a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the size of max_file_size and post_max_size in php.ini file and make them larger or just try to upload smaller image. I recently had similar problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks... Its the `.ini`s that always gets me :P